# PUT Request in Java

Tags: java, api, httprequest, put

I am trying to send PUT request in Java with header and body in json format. Body requires data with specific name 'input_data'. I am getting error like "input_data value not provided". Same code runs in Python as belows:

How can I write same code in Java?

Python code:

```py
url = "URL"
headers = {"admin_key":"0fdgdf0g64fr4h4e24z4df5xv"}
data = '''{
    "request": {
        "status": {
            "name": "Closed"
        }
    }
}'''
data = {'input_data': input_data}
response = requests.put(url, headers=headers, data=data)
print(response)
```

Java code:

```java
URL url = new URL("URL");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("PUT");

con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
con.setRequestProperty("admin_key", "0fdgdf0g64fr4h4e24z4df5xv");

Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
String input_data = "{
    \"request\": {
        \"status\": {
            \"name\": \"Closed\"
        }
    }
}";
parameters.put("input_data", input_data);
con.setDoOutput(true);
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
   for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : parameters.entrySet()) {
      result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
      result.append("=");
      result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

out.writeBytes(result.toString());
out.flush();
out.close();

int status = con.getResponseCode();
Reader streamReader = null;

if (status > 299) {
    streamReader = new InputStreamReader(con.getErrorStream());
} else {
    streamReader = new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream());
}
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
String inputLine;
StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    content.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();
con.disconnect();
```

Comment: where is your Java code?

Comment: We can't help unless you tell us what you tried. Please show us the Java code that does not work as expected.

Comment: Too much fictional code here to be able to assist easily

Comment: It is extremely unlikely that `DataOutputStream.writeBytes` is what you should be using here, as that will write a buffer prefixed with four bytes of the length of the buffer. Have you tried writing directly to the OutputStream of `con.getOutputStream()`, or better yet, wrap it in an `OutputStreamWriter` and get rid of your intermediate `StringBuilder`, instead writing directly to the stream.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not the exact answer to the question on why you are getting the error `input_data value not provided`. Mainly because code seems to be unnecessarily complex. Also it's difficult to say what's going on, especially when it's clear how the request is handled by the endpoint which you are calling at `URL`.

If you are using Java 11, you can simplify the code using JDK provided [HttpClient](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html) and should also give provide you more clear error when it fails.

Below is a code excerpt you can try in your method

```
String url = "YOUR URL";
String body = "{" +
            "    \"request\": {" +
            "        \"status\": {" +
            "            \"name\": \"Closed\"" +
            "        }" +
            "    }" +
            "}";

String data = "\"input_data\": "+ body;
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .PUT(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(data))
            .uri(URI.create(url))
            .setHeader("admin_key", "0fdgdf0g64fr4h4e24z4df5xv")
            .setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .build();

var client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

var response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

System.out.println(response.statusCode());
System.out.println(response.body());
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but I use Java 8. How can I do this in Java 8.